# Possible compatible ""structure" on the Lie algebra associated with a Lie group with respect to group structure

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

For simplicity, let us work on an example.
Regard $GL_r(\mathbb C)$ as a Lie group with associated Lie algebra $M_r(\mathbb C)$, then there exists a canonical so called exponential map:
$$\exp: M_r(\mathbb C)\to GL_r(\mathbb C).$$
My question is that is there any "structure" on $M_r(\mathbb C)$ that is compatible with the group structure and the exponential map?
Precisely, for $M_1\mapsto g_1=\exp(M_1)$ and $M_2\mapsto g_2=\exp(M_2)$, what is the possible "elements" $M\in M_r(\mathbb C)$ with $M\mapsto g_1g_2=\exp(M)$?
How does such a $M$ relate to $M_1$ and $M_2$?
What is the induced relation on eigenvalues?

Comment: How does such an $M$ relate to $M_1$ and $M_2$:  this is the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula).

Comment: BCH describes the group law in terms of the Lie algebra laws. Conversely, more complicated Lazard formulas describe the Lie algebras laws in terms of the group law. More simply, the exponential conjugates Lie algebra homomorphisms to Lie group homomorphisms.